# How to use htaccess, remove part of the url, point to subfolder and retain the URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to catch a URL with a specific prefix, remove the prefix, and let a subfolder serve it but retain the original URL at the same time.

Example:
[www.example.com/mypattern/module/script1](http://www.example.com/mypattern/module/script1)
-> /subfolder/module/script1
but it should retain the original URL

So far, I was able to make it work using,

```
RewriteRule ^mypattern/(.*)$ /server/public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Problem: the original URL also changed and included the server/public.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to have url `www.example.com/mypattern/module/script1` as it is on browser? If this is the case then from which file eg: indedx.php etc it should get served in backend?

Comment: it actually routes to laravel.  So I want to push /module/script1 to laravel.